# Matrix multiplication in OpenCV 2.4.9 (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to multiplication two matrix. For example `mat1` is `1*5(or 5*5)` and `mat2` is `5*5`. My code is:

```
Mat s2 = Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_8SC1);
Mat s3 = Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_8SC1);

gemm(s2, s3, 1, NULL, 0 , ad, 0);
```

But it does not work and breaks the program.

Comment: What error do you get? That probably tells you exactly why this is failing. Also, both of the matrices above are 5*5.

Comment: What is the error you got? Have you declared the output matrix `ad`?

Comment: declared the output matrix Mat ad; . I do not take any error. program when running it break.

Comment: What is the size and type of `ad`? And I have no idea what you mean by "program when running it break".

Comment: image of error :  http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-12/69821559409175436257.png

Comment: declare of ad : Mat ad = Mat(1, 5, CV_64FC1);

Comment: If `s2` and `s3` are both 5 by 5 matrices, then `ad` should also be a 5 by 5 matrix. Use `Mat ad = Mat(5, 5, CV_8SC1);`.

Comment: And while you're at it, make `s2` and `s3` of type `CV_64FC1`.

Comment: As long as the types are consistent. :)

Comment: @eigenchris `gemm` requires floats: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#gemm

Comment: thanks. my problem was type of s2, s3

Comment: @user3802201 That was my original thought, but that should have thrown an assertion failure.